# How can I fill sink holes?

Tags: lawn, soil, drainage

We recently purchased a 5-year-old house. It's a 3-acre lot with the house built on a raised hill in the middle. There are a couple of spots at the edge of the "developed" yard where the earth is sinking and holes opening up. I dug one out and can see it has been caused by logs in the fill and water running downhill. The spot is about 10 metres down from the septic field feed.

I'm going to run a [French drain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_drain) across the top of the area so water can be diverted away.

But I'm not sure of the best approach to filling the hole. My plan is to drop large rocks into the bottom and then add some washed gravel before covering back with top soil. Does that sound like a reasonable approach?

Comment: 3 acre = 1.2 hectares (ha) = 12,000 ㎡

Answer (score 2):

Rotting logs mean you either go to the bother & mess of digging the logs out, or you spend years filling the hole as they continue to rot - your choice.

If you don't remove the rotting logs, it really doesn't matter what you fill with (other than "not more stuff that will rot") since the logs will rot and the hole will need filled again, until they are gone. So, cheap dirt is just as good as large rocks or washed gravel unless the large rocks and washed gravel are cheaper than cheap dirt.

If leaving the wood, just fill the holes to a slight mound, and refill every time you notice them sinking again.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's a combination of rotting logs and too much water running beneath them. I'm going to pull the logs out. I live in Nova Scotia, the rocks, roots and logs are free and plentyful! I have to pay for dirt and I've got a pile of gravel.

Comment: They're in a spot that a path down to the water goes through so they've got to go.